# Responsive design layout with bleeding edges

Tags: css, responsive-design, transform

What would be the best approach for html/css structure for a document as the one pictured here:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7782299/sample/sample.jpg]

The center area is the actual browser window. I need the container div (along with its contents) to extend *past* the browser window (as I need to scale it down via transform: scale(0.xx); at some point to achieve a certain effect and I don't want the margins to be blank).

The container div would have full cover image for a background and the whole thing would need to be according to responsive design, maintain this structure regardless of how browser window is resized.

Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: This is not a tips or suggestions site...what code do you have? And what's the issue that's preventing you from getting your desired effect?

Comment: Please don't append the answer to the question. Answers have a separate place.

Comment: can't do that, the question is on hold. Can we 'unhold' this?

Comment: If you have discovered an answer, please post it as such; do not edit it into your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided, I would recommend setting a negative margin to achieve what you are looking for. Something like so:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left{
     margin-left: -5%;
     margin-bottom: -5%;
}
#right {
     margin-right: -5%;
     margin-bottom: -5%;
}
```

and then have percentage based width and height.. Hope this helps